# How to get route params in React functional component

Tags: reactjs

I want to print url params(:uname ,:unumber) through Profile functional component. Here is my code.

My route in App.js

```
 <Route path="/profile/:uname-:unumber" component={Profile} >
          <Profile />
        </Route>
```

I'm clicking profile url from Dashboard.js; this is my link

```
 <Link to={{
pathname: `/profile/${userDetail.name}-${userDetail.u_number}`,
}} >view profile</Link>
```

on click on this link it is generating a url for eg: 'http://localhost:3000/profile-mynamehere-747484' and it is redirecting to profile component. But how to print to access the uname and unumber in profile component. I tried like this but not works

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useHistory,useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "../Header";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

const Profile = ({uname, unumber}) => {
          console.log(uname); // here I want to print mynamehere from url, but not prints name
          console.log(unumber);// here I want to print 747484 from url, but not prints unumber
         return (
           <div>
           </div>
               );
      };
    export default Profile;
```

Comment: you aren't passing anything into profile.  You need to grab them in profile using useParams

Comment: Check `useParams` [link](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Profile you should useParams to get pass the uname & unumber:

```
import { useHistory,useParams } from "react-router-dom";

    const Profile = () => {
    const {uname, unumber} = useParams()
          console.log(uname);
          console.log(unumber); 
         return (
           <div>
           </div>
               );
      };
```

Answer (score 2):

use **UseParams** like this in profile component

```
const { uname,unumber } = useParams();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your profile component do the following:

```
  import React, {useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useHistory,useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "../Header";

const Profile = () => {
const {uname, unumber} = useParams()

          console.log(uname-unumber) 
         return (
           <div>
           </div>
               );
      };
    export default Profile;
```

Comment: @all thank u for helping me. Thanks a lot.